# How to deploy and host prebuilt Stripe checkout backend java code

Tags: java, reactjs, firebase, deployment, stripe-payments

I have recently tried to create my first E-Commerce site. Its is made with React on the frontend, and then I implemented a stripe pre-built checkout page to handle payments using java, following this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder
I am trying to deploy the application to firebase to host it, I can deploy  the React very easily, however I do not know how to deploy the Java, or if I even can on firebase.
Any help would be appreciated on how to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Firebase currently does not support Java](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/functions/code/languages):

> Cloud Functions current supports the Node.js 8 JavaScript Runtime, and the Node.js 10 Engine is in beta. You can choose a Node version it from your package.json. You can also choose to write your functions in TypeScript, using either Node.js version. The Python 3.7 runtime and Go 1.11 runtime is also avalible, but is currently only accessible from the Google Cloud Console.